# Twitter API v2 filtered stream in Tweepy

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy, twitter-api-v2

I am attempting to make a filtered stream on Twitter API v2, using tweepy library.
Here is my code:

```
client = tweepy.StreamingClient(
bearer_token = "Bearer_Token"
)

client.add_rules(tweepy.StreamRule("tweets_count:1000"))

response = client.filter(
expansions="author_id",
user_fields="id"
)
```

The problem is that I am not able to set a limit for the tweets I want to receive. If I manually stop the stream (keyboard interrupt), the response will be empty.
I want to be able to set a limit for the tweets or at least properly stop it (running in colab notebook), also I am not knowing where to find the received tweets along with their fields. I've searched alot but did not find an answer. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one of the problems you're having is that you've misunderstood the purpose of the "tweets_count" parameter.

My reading of the API docs suggests that its purpose is to return tweets from users who have a number of tweets on file greater than the tweet_count you specify.

It isn't intended to stop the stream once a maximum number of tweets have been returned.

Streamers are normally done by creating a subclass of StreamingClient and overriding one of the methods.

It's up to you how you process the tweets as they arrive, and in your case "response" is a data stream, not, say, a list or tuple.

Here's some skeleton code that I used as a basis for a streamer:

```
import tweepy

bearer_token = "some token"

class MyClient(tweepy.StreamingClient):

    def on_tweet(self, tweet):
        print(tweet)
        # or call some other processing

    def on_connect(self):
        print("connected to stream")



client = MyClient(
bearer_token=bearer_token,
)

client.add_rules(tweepy.StreamRule("tweets_count:1000"))

client.filter(expansions="author_id", user_fields="id")
```

Comment: yes, I know what tweets_count actually is, but I do not know how to store that "stream", or the results that I get. I guess now I understood how can I retrieve the stream. Thank you.